# Bad XAML still compiles with no error, then runtime error occurs in Xamarin.Forms project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**Context**

In my all projects (including a freshly created one) I can make typo's in my XAML, which then compiles with no error, no warning. 
Of course runtime an Exception throws.

**Question**

Is this normal or something went wrong in my Visual Studio 2017.3?

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at [this page in the Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings). If you use bindings in your XAML, don't forget to set the type of the binding context by specifying `x:DataType` or else the compilation of the bindings will (more or less) silently fail.

Answer (score 7):

This is normal when writing `Xaml` both for `Xamarin.Forms` and `WPF`

One benefit Xamarin does bring though is [Xaml Compliation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc/)

> XAML can be optionally compiled directly into intermediate language
>   (IL) with the XAML compiler (XAMLC).
>
> XAMLC offers a number of a benefits:
>
> - It performs compile-time checking of XAML, notifying the user of any
>     errors.
> - It removes some of the load and instantiation time for XAML
>     elements.
> - It helps to reduce the file size of the final assembly by no
>     longer including .xaml files.

Notice the first bullet point here:

> - It performs compile-time checking of XAML, notifying the user of any
>     errors.

To use this do the following:

> The following code example demonstrates enabling XAMLC at the assembly level:
>
> ```
> using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
> ...
> [assembly: XamlCompilation (XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
> namespace PhotoApp
> {
>    ...
> }
> ```